# Load a div in clockwise manner

Tags: jquery, html, css

Searched a lot but couldn't find a satisfactory solution anywhere. My objective is to load a circular image clockwise on page load. It is an image of a pie chart and I want to achieve this using jquery/css only.
I have tried using the `circleProgress()` plugin. The idea I have used here is to pre load the image and just show the circle progress load OVER it with transparent end color.

My question here is that is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Using this method, it shows a slight border of the original image which is not the desired output. 
Please note I do **NOT** want to rotate the image, just it to be loaded clockwise. Also this is not an actual pie chart, just an image of the pie chart. Hence I have not used SVG. Any suggestions using jquery `animate()` or anything like that will be very helpful. Thanks.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h1ud4421/7/)**

Comment: Is your background always white? Is it dynamic or static?

Comment: The background will remain static white. Won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I did—because you require an image to be in place of the red circle, we leave it untouched. However, we will have to wrap the circle/image with a wrapper element, and absolutely position two masking elements within in, each covering half (left or right sides) of the circle/image.

```
<div class="circle_wrapper">
    <div class="circle_red"></div>
    <div class="mask_left"></div>
    <div class="mask_right"></div>
</div>
```

And then we can simply use CSS3 animation to do the job. The logic is simple:

1. Create masking element that cover left and right handside. They will fill the height, but only half the width. Hide overflows.
2. Position pseudo-elements of identical dimensions within each side. For this we use the `::before` element (or you can use `::after`, that's also no issue).
3. Rotate them by 180deg, but in a staggered manner (right side first, left side after). The trick is to ensure that the animation state is frozen at its end state, so remember to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`.

You can always use JS to toggle a class name and trigger the animation, if you don't want the animation to appear right away on page load. **You should use vendor prefixes** for the `animation` and `@keyframe` declarations, in order to maximize cross-browser compatibility.

Here's the [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/h1ud4421/20/) if you want to see it working rightaway. If you want to see it [working with a sample image of a pie chart](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/n2ucpt7k/), I have it, too. Just remember to set image to `display: block` and define its dimensions. If you are confused of the exact mechanics, [I have made a fork that makes the individual masks obvious](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nzj6npeo/) :)

```
body {
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:white;
}
.circle_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.circle_red{ 
    background-color:red; 
    border-radius:50%;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

/* Masks */
.circle_wrapper > div[class^='mask'] {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.mask_left {
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
}
.mask_right {
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
}

/* Pseudo elements in masks */
.circle_wrapper > div[class^='mask']::before {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.mask_left::before {
    animation: leftHalf 2s 0s 1 linear forwards;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%; /* center right */
}
.mask_right::before {
    animation: rightHalf 2s 0s 1 linear forwards;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%; /* center left */
}


@keyframes leftHalf {
    0%  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
@keyframes rightHalf {
    0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50%  { transform: rotate(180deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/h1ud4421/20/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your fiddle links do not show the output. However I understand the idea here and shall try and implement it.

Comment: As I said in my answer, your browser might not support unprefixed animation syntax.

Comment: Updated the fiddle links, now they load prefixfree.js to dynamically add vendor prefixes.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! Appreciate your efforts and I got to learn something new as well! Cheers! Any chance this could be compatible to run in Safari?